# Spark Compressing files from Multiple partitions into Single partition with larger files

Tags: apache-spark, partitioning

I would like to take small parquet files that are spread out through multiple partition layers on s3 and compress them into larger files with a single partition back out to s3.

So in this example, I have 3 partition layers (`part1`, `part2`, `part3`). I would like to take this data and write it back out only partitioned by `part2`

For my first run through I used:

```
df = spark.read
.option("basePath", "s3://some_bucket/base/location/in/s3/")
.parquet("s3://some_bucket/base/location/in/s3/part1=*/part2=*/part3=*/")

df.write.partitionBy("part2").parquet("s3://some_bucket/different/location/")
```

This worked for the most part but this seems to still create smaller files. Since I'm not running a `coalesce` or `repartition`. This brings me to my question. Is there a way I can easily compress these files into larger files based on size/row counts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can easily compress these files into larger files based on size/row counts?

Not really. Spark doesn't provide any utilities which can be used to limit size of the output files, as each files corresponds in general to a single partition.

So `repartitioning` by the same column as used for `partitionBy` is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

option("maxRecordsPerFile", 400000)

use this option while writing the file.